# Navigation Bar item Become Title ( while slide, without disappear)

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

Im sorry if the Title of question isn't 100% correct. To be honest Im not sure how to describe my question. I have problem. I have app which has Navigation Controller (title is called List). In navigation controller I have "Add" item. When I touch the Item, new View Controller is called. When I touch Back button, which is called "List". When I do slide gesture to go back, Button < called "Title" disappear and again appear even if name is same - "Title". I made gif animation to be clear. Does anybody know how to make my app just slide the title without any (dis)appear? Thank you very much and sorry If my english is not best:)

[image: gif:]

Answer (score 1):

This is the standard `UINavigationController` behavior and I don't believe you can easily change this. Two options come to mind:

1. If you really want this feature, the simplest solution is to tell your navigation controller to not show the navigation bar:

   [image: no bar]

   Then you can add your own navigation bar to your scenes. You'll have to manually add back buttons that you hook up to IBAction that pops the view controller (or an unwind segue to the previous scene). If your app supports landscape mode, you may also want to tweak the rotation behavior so it's shorter in landscape mode than portrait mode (like the navigation controller does).

   By doing this, you still enjoy the navigation controller functionality (pushing and popping), though you're manually adding navigation bars to every scene. The UX isn't going to be identical and you lose interactive pop gesture, too, but it's probably the easiest was to achieve your desired transition animation.
2. If that's not adequate (e.g. you need interactive gesture for popping, etc.), then you can write this yourself, retiring the navigation controller entirely and then use custom interactive transitions. This was introduced in iOS 7 (see WWDC 2013 video [Custom Transitions Using View Controllers](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/?id=218)) and revised in iOS 8 (see WWDC 2014 video [View Controller Advancements in iOS 8](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/?id=214)).

Frankly, these both feel like heavy-handed solutions (especially the second one), but if you really want to change the animation of the navigation bar associated with the navigation controller, then these are two options. Personally, I'd step back and do a cost-benefit analysis of this endeavor and decide whether this is worth it for a fairly minor UI issue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Ill think about it